# HTML/CSS Icon Positioning Issue

Tags: css

Can someone pls help me with positioning icons.. I have this

[image]

and need to make this out of it

[image]

Comment: Please add some code...

Answer (score 1):

In these cases you should post link to plunker or something for better help. Without code it is harder to answer, but I'll try. Your HTML should look like this

```
<div class="item"><span class="icon">Your icon goes here</span><span class="text">Text near icon</span></div>
<div class="item"><span class="icon">Your icon goes here</span><span class="text">Text near icon</span></div>
<div class="item"><span class="icon">Your icon goes here</span><span class="text">Text near icon</span></div>
...
```

Your CSS should look like this :

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add your media queries to collapse those down or move them under your image on smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways

1. https://jsfiddle.net/LzgfLaxr/

   1

   1

   1

   1

   1

   1

   1

   1

   1

CSS

```
.grp1{
  float:left;
}
```

2. https://jsfiddle.net/z7cqL7he/ (arrangement will be responsive with the width of screen )

CSS

```
.grp-container{
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid #000;
height:70x;
}
.icon{
  width:40px;
  height:10px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
  margin:3px;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```